# C# multiplying methods in Unity2D by 3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods

Okay, so I have this project I'm working on that is effectively a Mario clone in function created in Unity2D. For some reason, it's calling OnTrigger/OnCollision methods three times (as shown by the fact it relays debug messages set to relay when OnCollision or OnTrigger is called three times, even though it's only supposed to do this once (see the picture attached)), even though I didn't write for it to do that. My code is as follows (sorry it's messy, I'm still new to C# and Unity2D).

[image: callthree]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private float moveDirection;
    public float jumpForce;
    [SerializeField] private bool isJumping = false;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool facingRight = true;

    public Transform ceilingCheck;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundObjects;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public float checkRadius;
    public GameObject camera;

    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip otherClip;

    public float score;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreCount;

    public float health;
    public TextMeshProUGUI lifeCount;

    public GameObject[] enemy;
    public GameObject deathBarrier;
    public GameObject nPC;
    public GameObject youHaveSoMuchToLiveFor;
    public GameObject youCannotEscape;

    public bool talking;
    public bool bossTimerStart;


    //nabs stuff before start so there's no lag and so you don't have to nab it yourself
    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        enemy = GetComponentsInParent<GameObject>(tag == "Enemy");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //get inputs
        ProcessInputs();

        //flip
        Animate();

        StartCoroutine(DoThings());

        scoreCount.text = "Score: " + score;
        lifeCount.text = "Health: " + health;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 3;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 8;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 3;
       

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 8;
            
        }

    

}

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //move
        if (!talking)
        {
            Move();
        }

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, groundObjects);
    }

    private void ProcessInputs()
    {
        moveDirection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            isJumping = true;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator DoThings()
    {
        while (talking)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            yield return null;
        }
    }


    private void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        if (isJumping)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce));
        }
        isJumping = false;

    }


    private void FlipCharacter()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);

    }

    private void Animate()
    {
        //flip
        if (moveDirection > 0 && !facingRight)
        {
            FlipCharacter();
        }
        if (moveDirection < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            FlipCharacter();
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Coin")
        {
            score += 10;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }

        if (other.tag == "Npc")
        {
            nPC.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (other.tag == "House")
        {
            youHaveSoMuchToLiveFor.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            talking = true;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Npc")
        {
            nPC.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (other.tag == "House")
        {
            youHaveSoMuchToLiveFor.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BossArea")
        {
            Debug.Log("uHOH CUTSCENE TIME WOOOOOO");
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            youCannotEscape.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "EnemyLeft")
        {
            Debug.Log("scream but right");
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(5000f, 200f));
            if (health > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("apparently let's check this");
                health -= 1;
            }
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Woooo());
                StartCoroutine(YouGonDie());
            }
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "EnemyRight")
        {
            Debug.Log("scream but left");
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-5000f, 200f));
            if (health > 0)
            {
                health -= 1;
            }
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Woooo());
                StartCoroutine(YouGonDie());
            }
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            Debug.Log("oopsie you got shot UwU");
            if (health > 0)
            {
                health -= 1;
            }
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Woooo());
                StartCoroutine(YouGonDie());
            }
        }
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "EnemyTop")
        {
            Debug.Log("bonk");
            Destroy(other.transform.parent.gameObject);
            score += 5;
        }
        if (other.gameObject == deathBarrier)
        {
            StartCoroutine(YouFellLol());
        }

        IEnumerator Woooo()
    {
            Debug.Log("istg i think this game is an elaborate moistcritikal reference, truly what i've been waiting for, yeah baby");
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1.2f);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

        IEnumerator YouGonDie()
        {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(otherClip, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.001f);
        }

        IEnumerator YouFellLol()
        {
            Debug.Log("Hey stinky! You fell uwu");
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.001f);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }


        
    }
    public void TalkingWith()
    {
        talking = true;
    }
    public void StopTalkingWith()
    {
        talking = false;
    }



}
```

It only started doing this after I added a function where on interaction with certain objects, the player stops moving until the interaction is over (used for NPC interactions and cutscenes). I was expecting it to only call once. Instead, it called three times.

Comment: probably you have other triggers or colliders around that are producing the ontriggerEnter extra calls

Comment: Where is `this is only supposed to be called once` logged in the code?

Comment: as said before me, check that objects are triggering the ontrigger, just use `other.transform.name` and see what comes out

Comment: Okay, so @amitklein, I tried this, and it said the name of the object only x3

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel where the if health > 0 on the collision enter

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you said,

> it is only supposed to be called once

Yes, that's true - with a little modifications. Its nature is to be called once for every collider near it with *OnTrigger* enabled.

To fix this, make sure that unwanted colliders are not interfering with the trigger, and that they don't all have *OnTrigger* enabled.

Comment: I checked, there's no unwanted colliders.